# Connection terminating unexpectedly in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the code to connect to MySql DB using Mysql connection handler, when I try to test the code using break point I see this exception.

```
Connection unexpectedly terminated
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: please clarify this: "when i try to test the code using break point" with some piece of code. telepathy mode: you have experienced the `max_allowed_packet` size limitation.

Comment: When i try to access remote DB thro' code am not able to connect, where as i can access localhost DB. con = new MySqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
con.Open(); <== Here is what i get, connection closed unexpectedly...